# xml transformation not getting required output

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have XML like

```
     <ChildAges>
         <Age>4</Age>
        <Age>1</Age>
        <Age>5</Age>
        <Age>2</Age>
       <Age>0</Age>
   </ChildAges>
```

I would like to replace the Ages less than 2 to Age 2.Output should be like

```
   <ChildAges>
     <Age>4</Age>
    <Age>2</Age>
    <Age>5</Age>
   <Age>2</Age>
   <Age>2</Age>
 </ChildAges>
```

Please suggest xsl.I tried like below.but not working.

```
                      <xsl:element name="ChildAges">
                                <xsl:for-each select="*:Age">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="Age[node() &lt; 2]">
                                               <Age>2</Age>
                                         </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:copy-of select="*:Age"/>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please learn about [the identity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) as a starting point as then you only need to add one template for your change:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Age[. &lt; 2]">
        <Age>2</Age>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LWf

Answer (score 1):

```
    <xsl:element name="ChildAges">
<xsl:for-each select="//Age">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test=". &lt; 2">
<Age>2</Age>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                            <xsl:element name="ChildAges">
                                <xsl:for-each select="*:ChildAges/*:Age">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="node() &lt; 2">
                                               <Age>2</Age>
                                         </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <Age>
                                                <xsl:value-of  select="node()"/>
                                            </Age>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
```